# In what sense are compact operators limits of finite-rank operators?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The convergence is in respect to what topology ? Can someone please write it mathematically ?

Comment: If $T$ is compact, there is a sequence of finite-rank operators $\{T_n\}$ such that the operator norm of $T_n - T$ approaches zero as $n$ tends to infinity. We write $\Vert T_n - T \Vert \xrightarrow{n\to \infty}0$.